# WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available

Tags: php, mysql, server, ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I've been trying to install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS having a lamp installed, php 7.2, mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2 and apache2.

and I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) article from digitalOcean, but when I came to the part that I need to run `sudo phpenmod mcrypt` I got a message saying..

> WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't
>   exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available

I am doing this on ubuntu installed in godaddy

Can you give best solution for this?

Comment: Have you installed **mcrypt** module? You can see the solution provided th this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/866985/phpenmod-mcrypt-and-phpenmod-mbstring-return-errors

Comment: I run this `sudo apt install php7.1-mcrypt && sudo apt install php7.2-mbstring` but yet the problem persist

Comment: The problem is its not under php7.2

Comment: You can try a symlink of 7.1 version in 7.2. `sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/`

Comment: @SomnathSinha, you can add this as an answer, because this is the answer of this question.

Comment: @Dimitar: Added as answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pointing to `php7.1-mcrypt` with `php7.2` will solve the issue here. Below are the steps to configure 7.1 version mcrypt with `php7.2`


**Install `php7.1-mcrypt`**

```
sudo apt install php7.1-mcrypt
```

**Create symbolic link to `php7.1-mcrypt`**

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.1/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/
```

**Enable `mcrypt` extension**

```
sudo phpenmod mcrypt
```

**Restart the FastCGI Process Manager service**

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
```

> **Note:**
>   The above solution is a workaround to enable mcrypt in php7.2 through apt till `php7.2-mcrypt` is not available.

Comment: as long as my research goes mcrypt is not supported in 7.2, right?

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 This happens to me https://askubuntu.com/questions/998199/warning-module-mcrypt-ini-file-doesnt-exist-under-etc-php-7-2-mods-available/1033064#1033064

Comment: Unable to locate package php7.1-mcrypt

Comment: You need to install php7.1 first

Comment: Worked for me on php7.3 as well

Comment: Use this instruction for php7.2 if you get "Unable to locate package php7.1-mcrypt" error:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1037418

Comment: Worked perfectly on 7.2. You guys need to add ondrej/php ppa and that should find the php7.1-mcrypt package. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Answer (score 3):

for **php-7.3** like mentioned above i had to execute this command

`sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mcrypt.ini /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/`

cause the version 7.0 comes by default.